# Identifying the missing part of the calculation

Tags: mathematics

The IQ question is,

(39+56)/60% = ?*3

Complete the equation by correctly identifying the missing part of the calculation from the list of options below.

where in the book answer is stated as 133/7.

I calculated the answer using base 10 but it doesn't produce the given answer. Any insight?

This was extracted from ADVANCED IQ TESTS by PHILIP CARTER

Comment: Considering
[@El-Guest's freethinking solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/99812),
this has potential as a good job interview question/puzzle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So

> (39+56) = 95; and 95/60% = 95/0.6 = 158.333 repeated.

Then,

> You have 3x = 158.333333 = 475/3, so x = 158.33333 /3 = 475/9.

However,

> Notice that 133/7 = 19. There’s a typo in the book, since 19 x 3 = 57, and (39+56)x60% = 57. The true question should have been (to get their answer): (39+56)x60% = ?x3.

Comment: This [`real`](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/real) solution demonstrates a general-purpose intelligence well beyond the calculation skill that the book seems intent to measure.